# How to get whitelisted with Yahoo! email addresses

Tags: email-bounces

I have been running into issues with getting our company email server compliant to mass email Yahoo addresses. A number of emails range from 200 to 250 emails; however, about 40% of them at least get bounced back saying too many senders.

Does anyone know of a form or tactic to get on Yahoo!'s mass email whitelist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This forum post here explains what I need to do. I figure it would be useful for anyone else trying to figure this out.

http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1217932